# Display only two items in legend

Tags: reporting-services

How do I go about only showing two items in my legend in my stacked chart?
I've got two stacks on each bar, each showing two individual items in the legend. I need two of those to be removed.

Here is a picture of how it looks (see the green box):

[image]

I need to remove the two items **"0 - Outstanding"** and **"1 - Outstanding"**.

I'm using this code to display the "Late issue":

```
=IIF(Count(IIF(Fields!Outstanding.Value = 1, 1, Nothing)) > 0,  "Late Issue",  Nothing)
```

And the "Not finished":

```
 =IIF(Fields!Outstanding.Value = 0, "Not finished", Nothing)
```

**Outstanding** is basically a binary value working much like a boolean value (1 being true and 0 being false).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Series Group Properties, `Group On` property use:

[image]

```
=IIF(Fields!Outstanding.Value=0, "Not Finished", "Late Issue")
```

This will leave you only two series groups `Late Issue` and `Not Finished`.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Actually managed to figure it out myself by setting the 'Do not show this series in a legend' for both stacks. I'll mark this as the answer, though as I'm hoping this might help someone else later on! :)